# Customized UITableView gives NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I am populating a UITableView and is given a strange error I cannot understand. I know you cannot solve this problem without more understanding about the project but does any one know what this error message means and what could be causing it.

```
2019-06-26 13:35:22.383456+0200 TapetDemo[97178:2284706] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to access the table view's visibleCells while they were in the process of being updated, which is not allowed. Table view: <UITableView: 0x7fb4f981f000; frame = (0 85; 375 812); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600003b30570>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000035e5640>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 44}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; dataSource: <_UIFilteredDataSource: 0x600003b30660>>'
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what your error says 
`'Attempted to access the table view's visibleCells while they were in the process of being updated, which is not allowed.`

it's almost impossible to know the problem without the actual code, but make sure the you're not doing what the error is saying.

Comment: Hi Yasser! Thank you for the quick feedback. Do you have any examples of what could be causing such an error message? Moreover, the error message says: Assertion failure in -[UITableView _visibleCellsUsingPresentationValues:]

Comment: it could be you're trying to update the values in the wrong order, for example you're updating them in the same time? or there's a problem with the data you're passing to the cell itself I'm not really sure what could be the cause. you might wanna make sure you're using `tableView.reloadData()` but also make sure you're not using it too much because it could be what causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have also come through such an Exception when I was using Collection View with Firebase UI. In which there are multiple delegates such as `array(_ array: FUIIndexArray, didChange ref: DatabaseReference, at index: UInt)` and `didAdd`, `didRemove`. In such a customize Collection view such above delegates automatically do the task of collection View reloading, If I manually try to do `reloadData()` in these function at that moment I faced such Inconsistency.

After looking at what code info you provided its tough to find what is the issue, but my above scenario might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here the reason for this is that you are going to use a particular cell before it is ready for you to use as the error message says. As a solution for this you can use that particular cells/ table view with another delegate method. Furthermore you will face this kind of issues when using table view with hidden contents and showing those contents while scrolling. As a solution for this issue you can use 
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}` delegate method or another delegate method according to the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message once, trying to update an image in a cell.
I accidentally used:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: <IndexPath>) as? <YOUR_TABLE_VIEW_CELL>
cell?.imageView.image = image
```

Instead of dequeueing:

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: <IndexPath>) as? <YOUR_TABLE_VIEW_CELL>
 cell?.imageView.image = image
```

Hope this helps anyone else who encounters this in the future.